# Ruby: How to Install a Plugin in a Git Repository

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I'm not new to programming, but brand new to Ruby. Everything's working, but I'm still missing a key concept: how do you install a plugin and where/how do you include it in an app?

Example:
I'm trying to use the Facebooker2 plugin: https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2. In the readme, step 1 is to "Install facebooker2 as a plugin in your rails app." I've run the command git clone https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2.git to download a read only version of the repository.

Do I then bundle that up using Bundler, or do I need to create a gem file in some way? Do I simply 
use gem to install it, or do I need to compile it into a gem?

Any help (terminal commands or otherwise) are extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're source is `source 'https://rubygems.org'` but the gem you need is specific to github and not part of the rubygems.org library, then you can add the git method to your gemfile. You can also select a specific branch version. For example, here I have the gem `cancan` being pulled from the github repository on the `2.0` branch.

```
gem "cancan", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git", :branch => "2.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the repo and it's set up as a gem.  You can simply add

```
gem 'facebooker2'
```

to your Gemfile (in the root of your project) and run

```
bundle install
```

to download it and add it to your list of installed gems, both in development and in production.

Rails used to include the concept of plugins (added to your /vendor/plugins directory) but that's been dropped in favor of gems.